# ORACLE procedure crashes after recreating View that is using it

Tags: asp.net, oracle, view, iis-7.5

It happens that procedure1 sometimes crashes, after I recreate View that is using it, or recompile procedure2 that is using procedure1.

After I recompile with no changes made to procedure1 (that has been chrashed) all works fine.

.NET web applications (MVC 3, framework 4.5., EF 4.0, ODAC 11.2.0, IIS 7.5 application pool) with 5000 users use this procedure.

My question is why does this happens and how to counter it?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: It would maybe help to tell us what "crashes" means?

Comment: I ment that procedure has red x in sql developer and can't be called from web application until I recompile it.

Comment: I don't know what a "red X" means.  Sorry. If you click on the procedure, the details pane on the right shows an "Errors" Tab.  There should be some error displayed.

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to worry about.

The red "X" in SQL Developer merely indicates that Oracle has marked the procedure as "Invalid". Nothing has "crashed". An invalid procedure can mean one of two things:

(1) the last time the procedure was compiled, there was a compilation error - this is a problem that you'd have to resolve (e.g. by correcting the syntax).

(2) something the procedure depends on (e.g. a view) has changed - and the procedure needs to be recompiled.

In your case (2) is the most likely cause. The good news is, Oracle will *automatically recompile* the procedure the first time it is run, so you don't need to do anything.

But if you want to be sure, just right-click on the procedure and choose "Compile".

Or, in a SQL window run the following command:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE myprocname COMPILE;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but in my case oracle does not recompile the procedure automatically meaning I can't run the procedure from applications. Does this feature need to be enabled? I have no errors in procedure and when I manually recompile it, it compiles ok and i can call procedure from applications again.

Comment: Nothing needs to be enabled. When you try to run the procedure, what error is it reporting?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that Jeffrey Kemp's answer that: 
"Oracle will automatically recompile the procedure the first time it is run, so you don't need to do anything."

Is generaly true. I say generaly because it compiles if oracle procedure is called from Oracle (e.g. other procedure or sql statement). But in my case procedure was called from .net application and in this situation invalid oracle procedure is not automatically recompiled if something that procedure dependes on has changed. Putting procedure into package solves the issue, because package in oracle does not change state even if dependant objects are changed.

Other solution is also to change init.ora parameter remote_dependencies_mode from value timestamp to value signature. (not tried) But then you get procedure invalid if you add parameter into procedure and call it from .net app for the first time... so it has it's drawback.